# Why does my Merge Sort Implementation Require the Input be offset?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Last year in an assignment for my algorithms class, I was tasked with implementing three different sorting algorithms in the programming language of my choice. Although I managed to successfully implement all three of them in C, I was left with an annoying idiosyncrasy in my merge sort: It will only sort the inputted data correctly if I start with size-1 rather than size for the right index of the array. Any ideas as to the cause?

Both the mergeSort and merge functions are provided below:

```
void mergeSort(int* array, int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int q = (int)floor((p + r) / 2);
        mergeSort(array, p, q);
        mergeSort(array, q + 1, r);
        merge(array, p, q, r);
    }
}

void merge(int* array, int p, int q, int r)
{

    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int *L = (int*)malloc((n1 + 2) * sizeof(int));
    int *R = (int*)malloc((n2 + 2) * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++)
    {
        L[i] = array[p + i - 1];
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= n2; j++)
    {
        R[j] = array[q + j];
    }
    L[n1+1] = INT_MAX;
    R[n2+1] = INT_MAX;

    int i = 1, j = 1;

    for (int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            array[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            array[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    free(L);
    free(R);
}
```

I changed the offset of every variable in the algorithm at one point to see what was causing the issue but this only served to compound matters.

Comment: Don't cast `void *`.  Prefer passing a variable to `sizeof` instead of a type.  It's a little shorter as you don't need the `()`, you don't repeat the type name, and you will find it's quite mechanical: `some_type *x = malloc(sizeof *x)` which means less chance of errors.

Comment: L[0] and R[0] are uninitialized.  Usually you iterate from 0 to < n.  Consider using memcpy instead.

Answer (score 1):

The offset is due to the way the parameters and local variables are being used in the question's implementation of merge sort. Example of a typical top down merge sort that only does an initial copy in order to avoid copy back after each merge, instead alternating the direction of merge depending of level of recursion.

```
void Merge(int a[], int bgn, int mid, int end, int b[])
{
int i, j, k;
    i = bgn, j = mid, k = bgn;
    while(1){
        if(a[i] <= a[j]){               // if left smaller
            b[k++] = a[i++];            //  copy left element
            if(i < mid)                 //  if not end of left run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of right run
                b[k++] = a[j++];
            while(j < end);
            break;                      //   and break
        } else {                        // else right smaller
            b[k++] = a[j++];            //  copy right element
            if(j < end)                 //  if not end of right run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of left run
                b[k++] = a[i++];
            while(i < mid);
            break;                      //   and break
        }
    }
}

void MergeSortR(int b[], int bgn, int end, int a[])
{
    if (end - bgn <= 1)                 // if run size == 1
        return;                         //   consider it sorted
    int mid = (end + bgn) / 2;
    MergeSortR(a, bgn, mid, b);
    MergeSortR(a, mid, end, b);
    Merge(b, bgn, mid, end, a);
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int n)          // n = size (not size-1)
{
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    int *b = malloc(n*sizeof(int));     // 1 time allocate and copy
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = a[i];
    MergeSortR(b, 0, n, a);             // sort data from b[] into a[]
    free(b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to rewrite my program with these changes in mind when I get a chance and see what happens.